# Need suggestion in choosing an effective wireless Transmitter and Receiver

Tags: wireless, receiver, transmitter

My requirement is to transmit a binary form of data from one Road Junction to another road junction which is around 4 to 5 km away.

I am going to get the traffic information from each road in the form of binary (4 bits) and transmit this data to the connected junctions of my current traffic measured junction.

So I want to transmit a binary form (For ex: 1010) to that junction.

In the other junctions I have a Receiver which receives this binary form of data and manipulates this. So for this requirement which Transmitter and Receiver is good?
I have an option to use FM transmitter and FM receiver based on my past experience. But I want to explore things and find Transmitter and Receiver other than FM transmitter and Receiver.

I hope you got it right. I don't know If I am overlooking anything here.

Comment: How reliable does the system need to be? Do you have access to a lot of power? Are you cost constrained?

Comment: @Gallamine - My setup should be cost effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XBEE (XBEE Pro to be precise) is a good option if you don't have obstacles in between... XBEE simulates Wired communication over Air. All you need to do is get Two XBEE Modules. It's same like communicating over RS-232. Whatever you'll write in Your Serial Buffer, it will be transmitted over wireless medium. Moreover, there are some Readymade protocol stacks available in market by which you can do Mesh Networking.

But Keep in mind that, XBEE will work for the distance you mentioned only if it is obstacle free or less obstacles.

Comment: What about use directional antennas?

Comment: Yes, Antenna will Definitely increase the range but my experience is Obstacles reduce range considerably.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, remember, you have to reduce your output power to meet maximum radiated power guidelines if you go directional. Most guidelines are written as a maximum field intensity. This means that radiating power in all directions or only just one, your range in that direction does not change.

Comment: @Swanand:What about the expected cost of this one ?

Comment: @iRobot : I got it from SparkFun. [link]http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/111   I am not sure about the range you require but here are few models to which you can connect the antenna! Have a look at it. Go for XBEE **PRO**!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an [xbee](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-series1-module.jsp#overview). i think this will suit your needs.

Comment: @kortuk: yeah its a cool move for you to add a link. but i think any decent person with a functioning brain, is able to take a phrase and find something after it ;).i will not say what to use, since its OBVIOUS . no insult ^^

Comment: anyone with a functioning brain can also link to a product they know the name of. The value in this site is that you give a detailed and functional explanation. I know xbee, every time someone asks a wireless question I could just post your answer, but that does not tell them WHY it is a good choice.

Comment: ok youre right. i should have explained it a little more and point to something.